# Overriding css of a TextField component in Native Script

Tags: css, nativescript

I am trying to change the styles of a TextField element in Native Script for Android. At the moment I have got the text field displayed in black. I want to turn it white. Since the background is dark.

```
<TextField cssClass="tf_password" hint="Password" id="password" text="{{ user.password }}" secure="true"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text white and the background black you can set this in your CSS file:

```
#password {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I have got this: https://gyazo.com/fcea7a75219f81645690b43ec4a22375 and I need this: https://gyazo.com/a568ccc75aec8cd58e12d9a9d92e045e

Comment: If that CSS doesn't work it's more than likely you'll need to look into hooking into the native APIs and changing the properties of the native widgets.

Comment: Actually the css is slightly wrong; I'm pretty sure that NativeScript does NOT support the **!important** attribute.  By including it; you might confuse the CSS processor.  I would do that css; but leave off the !important.

Comment: 1 small question :  how can i make it look like text area i mean multiline (from HTML) ? @MikeResoli

Comment: @HardikVaghani If you want a multi-line textbox in NativeScript, use the TextView (https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components#textview). It will provide the necessary native iOS/Android UI for multi-line text editing.

Comment: !important [is not supported](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4969#issuecomment-338118984) in NativeScript

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not how to change the text color of a TextField but the placeholder color:

```
#password {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;

  placeholder-color: #fff; /* ideally different color than normal color */
}
```

You can see [a working example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=HR92UG&v=3) in NativeScript Playground

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of `TextField`, it that case you can simply give color property to `TextField`. If you are looking to change hint color than you can use the placeholder-color property:

```
<TextField hint="Password" id="password" text="{{ user.password }}"> 
</TextField>
```

The CSS would be

```css
TextField {
     color: #ffffff; // used to define color of input field
     placeholder-color: #000000; // used to define color of hint
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ?

Comment: @KishanBharda If you want to change the color of TextField, it that case you can simply give color property to TextField.
if you are looking to change hint color than you can use the placeholder-color property.
I hope it helps!